# Получение выборки из БД с соблюдением переноса строки

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name, text  FROM review order by id desc limit 3"); 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     ?>
     <h3><a title="title"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a></h3>
     <p><?php echo $row['text'] ?></p>
```

В данном случае текст это массив каждый элемент которого содержит много различных абзацев которые получаем из БД и они выводятся последовательно. Как сделать вывод текста с соблюдением  переноса строки?

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name, text  FROM review
                       order by id desc 
        limit 3"); 
                        mysql_close();
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            ?>


                            <h3><a title="title"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $row['text'] ?></p>

Comment: что это еще за коммент? пишите код в вопросе, редактируйте!

Comment: В чём проблема? `<br>` для переноса строки

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name, text FROM news order by id desc limit 3");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $name = $row['name'];
  $text= $row['text'];
  echo "
   <h3><a title='title'>$name</a></h3>
   <p>$text</p><br>
  ";
 }`

Comment: Дмитрий Гвоздь документ был создан с полным текстом кода, после сохранения я увидел что основная часть кода обрезана и добавил её в комментарии, если вы дадите ссылку на причину этого буду благодарен. Хотя по факту интересует ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Ув. Doofy я попробовал Ваш код не подходит (мог неправильно что -то сделать), насколько я понимаю в данном случае вывод происходит через цикл , обновлением  которого является "/n" (он является символом переноса строки в БД)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name, text  FROM review order by id desc limit 3"); 
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$text = str_replace("\n","<br>",$row['text']);

     ?>
     <h3><a title="title"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></a></h3>
     <p><?php echo $text ?></p>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Данный цикл полностью решил проблему.